# How can i sniff/dump HTTP protocol as ASCII for a port with tcpdump or altenative?

Tags: monitoring, http, tcpdump, packet-sniffer

I need to view how an application is sending and is receiving traffic through a http protocol that it comunicates on localhost (it has an embeded port coded with .gz)
I'm sure it's some XML that it sends and receives but i want to sniff it , and then analize it

Is this possible somehow with Tcpdump? there i can see only that it connects but not the actual send receive

Comment: Your use of `.gz` makes me think this is on Linux? You might want to specify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ngrep is very useful for this. Something as simple as

```
ngrep -W byline port 80
```

would work, but you can filter on the content of the requests too (hence the grep part of the name), and it prints out the packet payload:

```
ngrep -W byline some_string port 80
```

Comment: You need root permissions to run this right?

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to use tcpdump a command like this `tcpdump -s 0 -A -qn filters` should give you what you want.  The `-s 0` sets the packet size and `-A` dumps ascii.  Instead of `-A` you might also like `-X` which will provide you the output in a hexdump style format.

You could also use wireshark, and once you are done capturing just right-click on one of the packets and select the 'Follow TCP Stream'.

Comment: yes but i don't have a X11 interface, tcpdump is fine :) thank you

Comment: You could always use a forwarded X11 through SSH to your workstation.  You could `tcpdump -s 0 -w filename.dmp` to save a capture which you can open from wireshark somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

I've done quite a lot of this with wireshark. Sniff the traffic I want with tcpdump, ship it to somewhere I can launch Wireshark, and then view the trace with Wireshark. Tracing the TCP session gives me the request and answer in a nice ASCII form. Works great.